# In Hive. Can I partition(my_partition=some_function())?

Tags: sql, database, hive

My goal is:

Process yesterday's data, and put the result into another table.

So I wrote this query, but `partition(d=my_yesterday())` seems not working.

```
insert overwrite table t1 partition(d=my_yesterday())
    select my_udtf(a, b, c) as (e, f, g, h) from t2
    where d=my_yesterday();
```

Comment: Any reason you are using a UDF in order to get yesterday date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict
;

insert overwrite table t1 partition(d)
select  m.*,t2.d
from    t2
      lateral view outer  my_udtf(a, b, c) m as e, f, g, h
where  d=my_yesterday()
;
```